# Specify Sequelize sqlite path on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, electron, sequelize.js

I've been developing an Electron app in Linux using Sequelize with sqlite3, and everything works great. I connect to databases like this:

```
new Sequelize("sqlite:" + myPath);
```

Where myPath has been in the form of '/home/.../someDB.db'

However, I tried running my project on Windows and ran into a problem connecting to the db.

I can connect to the db if I use 'someDB.DB' for myPath, but when myPath is an absolute in the form 'C:...\someDB.db' I get an error:

> C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:868 Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
>       at Database.connections.(anonymous function).lib.Database.err (C:\projectPath\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\connection-manager.js:66:63)
>   printWarning @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:868
>   formatAndLogError @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:593
>   fireRejectionEvent @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:618
>   Promise._notifyUnhandledRejection @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:64
>   (anonymous) @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:43
>   setTimeout (async)
>   Promise._ensurePossibleRejectionHandled @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:42
>   Promise._reject @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:658
>   Promise._settlePromise @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:584
>   Promise._settlePromise0 @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614
>   Promise._settlePromises @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:689
>   Async._drainQueue @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133
>   Async._drainQueues @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143
>   Async.drainQueues @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17
>   Async Call
>   schedule @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\schedule.js:18
>   Async._queueTick @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:152
>   AsyncSettlePromises @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:88
>   Promise._reject @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:656
>   Promise._settlePromise @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:566
>   Promise._settlePromise0 @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614
>   Promise._settlePromises @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:689
>   Async._drainQueue @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133
>   Async._drainQueues @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143
>   Async.drainQueues @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17
>   Async Call
>   schedule @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\schedule.js:18
>   Async._queueTick @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:152
>   AsyncSettlePromises @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:88
>   Promise._reject @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:656
>   Promise._settlePromise @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:566
>   Promise._settlePromise0 @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614
>   Promise._settlePromises @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:689
>   Async._drainQueue @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133
>   Async._drainQueues @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143
>   Async.drainQueues @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17
>   Async Call
>   schedule @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\schedule.js:18
>   Async._queueTick @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:152
>   AsyncSettlePromises @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:88
>   Promise._reject @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:656
>   Promise._rejectCallback @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:474
>   (anonymous) @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:486
>   connections.(anonymous function).lib.Database.err @ C:\projectPath\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\connection-manager.js:66

How should I go about connecting to sqlite databases with Sequelize on Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized the solution was just to use the more verbose constructor:

```
new Sequelize('', '', '', {
        dialect: 'sqlite',
        storage: myPath
      });
```